# How to define a function that returns a function in clisp

Tags: clisp

Here is a function I defined in Scheme:

```
(define (multn n) (lambda (x) (* x n)))
```

and when I type

```
((multn 7) 5)
```

it gives 35.

However, when I used Clisp:

```
(defun multn (n) (lambda (x) (* x n)))
```

it gives me error: 'EVAL: (MULTN 7) is not a function name; try using a symbol instead'

How can I get it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~strandh/Teaching/Langages-Enchasses/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/diff-scheme.html

Comment: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch27/appendix-cl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `funcall` because of separate namespaces in Common Lisp:

```
[1]> (defun multn (n) (lambda (x) (* x n)))
MULTN
[2]> (funcall (multn 7) 5)
35
```

See for example [the Common Lisp cookbook](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/functions.html) for an in-depth explanation.